# Factorial Divides Rising Power Proof Help

Tags: factorial, congruences, pigeonhole-principle

I'm trying to prove the following:

$m^{\overline n} \equiv 0 \bmod n!$

Where $m^{\overline n} = m\left({m+1}\right)\left({m+2}\right)\ldots\left({m+n-1}\right)$, the product of $n$ successive natural numbers $\ge 1$.

I tried induction, but couldn't figure out how to make the induction step.

I also tried assuming the negation and then reducing it to a system of congruences $\bmod n!$:

$m \equiv 1, 2, \ldots, n!-1$

$m+1 \equiv 1, 2, \ldots, n!-1$

$\vdots$

$m + n - 1 \equiv 1, 2, \ldots, n!-1$

but couldn't get a contradiction.

My intuition tells me that this can be proved using the pigeonhole principle. That is, my hunch is that $\left\{m, m+1, m+2, \ldots, m+n-1\right\}$ has to contain the factors of $n!$. Is my intuition correct? If not, how else should I prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest proof of this I know is that the binomial coefficient $\binom ab$ is an integer for suitably chosen $a$ and $b$. There are combinatorial proofs and induction proofs of that.

I mention this because the link with binomial coefficients does not seem to be mentioned very often in this context, yet the problems are identical.

Comment: The context of my question is I'm trying to prove that $\binom a b \in \mathbb N$ without using a counting argument. So while I appreciate the suggestion, it would be circular in the context I'm using it in

Comment: @GFauxPas Then prove the coefficients are integers using induction (Pascal's Triangle)

Comment: Isn't the original question more general?

Comment: The original question is about whether the product of $n$ successive integers is divisible by $n!$. If you examine $\binom {m+n-1}n$ you will find that does the trick. If one of the successive integers is $0$ you are done anyway, and if they are all negative, you change the sign and use the positive case.